# Prove this property of rational upper bounds of $\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x^2<2\}$

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, rational-numbers

> Prove or disprove that if $\frac ab$ ($a$, $b\in\Bbb Z$) is in upper bound of $\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x^2<2\}$, then $a^2>2b^2$. Do not introduce real numbers yet.

I suppose this is true, but it seems hard to prove it using only knowledge prior to the definition of rational number set. I thought of proving by contradiction, say $\frac ab$ is an upper bound (namely, for all $x\in\Bbb Q$, $x^2<2$, $x\le\frac ab$), and assume $a^2\le2b^2$. Since $a^2\ne2b^2$ by number theory, then $a^2\le2b^2-1$.

I don't know how to continue. Maybe we need to find $x\in\Bbb Q$, $x^2<2$ such that $x>\frac ab$. But how to do this?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4099532/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/729306/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/130504/42969. If $a^2/b^2 < 2$ then you can find $p, q$ with $a^2/b^2 < p^2/q^2 < 2$.

Comment: For $x:=\frac{4ab}{2b^2+a^2}$, we have $2-x^2=2\frac{(2b^2-a^2)^2}{(2b^2+a^2)^2}>0$ and $x\frac ba-1=\frac{2b^2-a^2}{2b^2+a^2}>0$.